# SQL stored procedure priority

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a few tables within a store procedure and I have a question regarding the order in which i can create them.

I do the following:

- INSERT stuff into Table 1
- INSERT certain stuff into Table 2 from Table 1
- INSERT more certain stuff into Table 3 from Table 1 join Table 2

I will need Table 1 to be populated before moving on to Table 2 and Table 3.

Do I need to have two separate stored procedures? One to populate Table 1 then when complete it can call another stored procedure to populate the other tables?

Thanks!

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1):

You can run as many queries as you want from a single SP. It is therefore not necessary to create multiple SPs for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can*.  *Should* you?  That depends -

- Is the logic to insert into Table1 complex enough that you want to resuse it as much as possible?  Then make it its own procedure.
- Would you *never* insert into Table1 without also inserting into tables 2 and 3?  Then bundle it all together.

You can get both by creating insert sproc for the individual tables and then bundling them into an overarching sproc:

{pseudo-code}:

```
sproc A
    call sproc to insert into table 1
    call sproc to insert into table 2
    call sproc to insert into table 3
end
```

If your question is:  Will sproc 1 be completed befoer the other two sprocs start, then the answer is yes, whether you create one sproc or several.